# Postgres 8.4 and Rails4.2.3 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

> PG::Error: ERROR:  column "a.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: SELECT A.id, A.name, COUNT(DISTINCT tendercats.tender_Id) as...
>                  ^

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT tendercats.tender_Id) as total 
FROM  tender_categories A 
  LEFT JOIN tender_categories B ON A.id  = B.tender_category_id  
  LEFT JOIN tendercats ON (tendercats.tender_category_id  = B.id) OR (tendercats.tender_category_id  = A.id)  
  JOIN tenders ts ON tendercats.tender_category_id  = ts.id  
WHERE  A.tender_category_id  is NULL 
 AND  (ts.cdate  > '2015-08-31') 
 AND  ts.language_id  = 1 
ORDER BY A.id, A.name
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? Plus: if you are **really** using Postgres 8.4 you should upgrade as soon as possible to a maintained and supported version (e.g. 9.4)

Comment: There are also many, many questions regarding this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+must+appear+in+the+GROUP+BY+clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name